# Unable to delete messages using JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail to access an Exchange mailbox (private to the company I work for).  My applicable code is as follows:

```
Store store = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null).getStore("imap");
store.connect(...stuff...);
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
int numOfMessages = inbox.getMessageCount();
for (int i = 1; i<=numOfMessages; i++){
    Message message = inbox.getMessage(i);
    message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
    System.out.println(message.getSubject());
}
inbox.close(true);
store.close();
```

It is accessing and printing out all of the message names properly.  However, with each run through, it is printing the same names over and over, indicating that they weren't actually deleting.

**Resolution**: *I found that I was throwing an error before the `inbox.close(true)` (in code I deemed inapplicable).  I'm not marking it as an answer, because this isn't a real answer.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call the `saveChanges` method on your `Message` object. Javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Message.html#saveChanges%28%29).

Comment: I'm getting a "javax.mail.IllegalWriteException: IMAPMessage is read-only"...and after doing research, it looks like saveChanges() is not the way to interact with IMAP

Comment: Ah, I know what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks for the help...it was a logic error in my code.